# In large sample theory does $\hat{\theta} \sim N(\theta, I^{-1}(\hat{\theta}))$ refer to only diagonal entries of $Cov(\hat{\theta})$?

Tags: asymptotics

In large sample theory does $\hat{\theta} \sim N(\theta, I^{-1}(\hat{\theta})$) implicitly mean that only diagonal entries of $Cov(\hat{\theta})=I^{-1}(\hat{\theta})$?

Comment: No, certainly not, this is the full matrix inverse

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen So how are $Cov$ and variance interchangeable like this?

Comment: In multivariate setting the variance-covariance matrix is often just denoted as variance, just to keep same terminology as the scalar case.

Comment: You can use transformation of variables to whiten your data such that the covariance matrix becomes diagonal.

Comment: It can -- but interest usually focuses on the parameters in the problem, rather than the specific linear combinations of them that happen to be uncorrelated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.

However, if $I(\theta) = W^T W$, you can transform $\hat\theta$ as $\hat\eta = W \hat\theta$, where $W = I^{1/2}(\theta)$. Then the whitened random variable $\hat\eta$ has a diagonal covariance matrix.

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Cov}(\hat \eta) & = W \operatorname{Cov}(\hat \theta) W^T = I^{1/2}(\theta) I^{-1}(\theta) I^{1/2}(\theta) \\[10pt]
& = I^{1/2}(\theta) I^{-1/2}(\theta) I^{-1/2}(\theta) I^{1/2}(\theta) = I.
\end{align}